# JSON format for d3 Choropleth

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js

I'm using d3Queue with a d3 Choropleth.  When my data is in CSV format, it works fine:

**CSV Data:**

```
state, count
1, 100
2, 200
3, 300
```

and

```
.defer(d3.csv, data, function(d) {
  rateById.set(d.state, +d.count); 
})
```

However, now my data is in JSON format.

**JSON Data:**

```
[
  {
    state: 1,
    count: 100
  },
  {
    state: 2,
    count: 200
  }
]
```

And I changed my `.defer` to this:

```
.defer(d3.json, data, function(d) {
  rateById.set(d.state, +d.count); 
})
```

But it is throwing the error: **"Cannot read property 'state' of null"**.  Does this mean the data is not being passed through, or that I'm messing up reading the JSON?

Comment: What is the output of console.log(d) prior to 'rateById.set(d.state, +d.count);'? That should give you a clue as to what is available to you within the closure.

Comment: Hmm... it's *null*...

Comment: What about d3.json and data?

Comment: It returns this (stringified)  `[{"state":23,"count":15},{"state":53,"count":360},{"state":11,"count":8},{"state":5,"count":34},{"state":21,"count":48},{"state":55,"count":81},{"state":10,"count":25},{"state":54,"count":47},{"state":15,"count":46},{"state":12,"count":367},...` so it's passing the data properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading over the queue.js API, it looks like this should work:

```
.defer(d3.json, data) // .defer(task, [arguments]);
.await(function(d) { 
    rateById.set(d.state, +d.count); 
}); // .await(callback)
```

[Link to the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/queue)

Comment: Isn't that basically what I'm doing?

Comment: Anyway, I tried what you said, and now I'm getting another random error... so hopefully that's progress!

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, the arguments after d3.json in your .defer(d3.json, data, ...) are arguments for retrieving your data from the server. The actual data doesn't seem to be available until one reaches the .await() callback. Of course, this assumes their API documentation is accurate and up to date. Let me know if I can help!